# Gentoo CPU_FLAGS_X86 doesn't work

Tags: upgrade, gentoo, emerge

I havn't updated my system for few months and found i have to add new option to my `make.conf`. Ok, so now i have

```
CPU_FLAGS_X86="aes avx avx2 fma3 mmx mmxext popcnt sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3"
```

But when

```
 sudo emerge --update --newuse --deep --with-bdeps=y @world -p
```

I have rows like

```
 [ebuild   R    ] media-sound/lame-3.99.5-r1  USE="-cpu_flags_x86_mmx%"
```

So it just ignores CPU USE FLAGS (e.g. -cpu_flags_x86_mmx) and hasn't special scope for CPU_FLAGS_X86. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reselect profile like

```
eselect profile set 6
```